# C# XPathSelectElement returns null

Tags: c#, xpath

I am trying to use the XPathSelectElement method of the System.Xml.XPath namespace but for some reason it always returns null, and I have no idea why.

Here is the code:

```
TextReader stream = new StreamReader("config.ini");
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
XElement xml = XElement.Load(reader);

XElement file = xml.XPathSelectElement("Config/File");
```

Here is the XML file it is trying to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Config>
 <File>serp_feed.xml</File>
</Config>
```

I have tried many things (adding a namespace table, changing the XPath, etc.) but nothing works!

Any ideas?

Comment: Having a file named `.ini` that *isn't* in standard ini-file format is going to confuse someone at some point :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well with `XElement.Load` the variable named `xml` is the root element, the "Config" element of the XML sample you posted. And if you use the path `Config/File` on that element as the context node you are looking for a child element named "Config" having a descendant "File" element. The "Config" element does not have a "Config" child element, it only has a "File" child element. So you want the XPath `File` or you need `XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("config.ini)`, then your path works.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
XElement file = xml.XPathSelectElement("File")
```

Because you are using `XElement.Load` rather than `XDocument.Load` the root will be the element rather that the document, hence the step in the XPath expression is not required.